# FactoryBot is not creating the associated models list in the after create callback

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have two factories as follows:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :proofread_document do

    factory :proofread_document_with_paragraphs do
      after(:create) {|instance| create_list(:paragraph, 5, proofread_document: instance) }
    end
  end
end

    FactoryBot.define do
      factory :paragraph do
        level { 1 }
        association :proofread_document
    end
end
```

In my RSpec test:

```
  describe '#number_of_paragraphs_for' do

    let(:proofread_document) { create(:proofread_document_with_paragraphs)}

    it 'returns the number of paragraphs for the given level' do
      expect(proofread_document.number_of_paragraphs_for("level_1")).to eq(1)
    end
  end
```

The test fails because there are no paragraphs:

```
proofead_document.paragraphs
=> []
```

Why are the associated paragraph objects not being created?

Comment: Have you checked if it really doesn't create associated objects? Maybe there is a bug somewhere else? Add smth like `expect(Paragraph.count).to eq(5)` in your test to check if they exist.

Also: please provide your ProofreadDocument and Paragraph models code so we can help.

Comment: Can you share the implementation of `number_of_paragraphs_for`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

In my paragraphs model I had placed a default scope as follows:

```
default_scope :minimum_word_count,  ->{ where(proofread_word_count: MINIMUM_LEVEL_DATA_WORD_COUNT..Float::INFINITY)}
```

This caused some issues as the paragraph I was saving in my tests had a word count too low for the parameters defined in this scope.

@P.Boro and @rewritten helped by getting me to re-check my models and scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Associations are not magically reloaded on existing instances. This is not due to FactoryBot, but to ActiveRecord itself.

```
# example with activerecord:

class Foo
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
end

foo = Foo.first
foo.bars
# => []
3.times { Bar.create(foo: foo) }
foo.bars
# => []
foo.reload.bars
# => [<#Bar ...>, <#Bar ...>, <#Bar ...>]
```

So you just need to reload the record (or just the association)

```
after(:create) do |inst|
  create_list(...)
  inst.paragraphs.reload
  # or inst.reload
end
```

Comment: There is no need for reloading association in OP example as it was not cached.

Comment: True that. It might be something else then.

Comment: Not sure why you got a down vote for this. This is an actual known problem (not that it's a problem because factory_bot runs outside the context of orm). If you create in a callback you have to reload the object to access associated objects. See https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/585